# Powershell: some modules unavailable when called via CreateProcess()

Tags: winapi, powershell, module, createprocess

Under what conditions do some PowerShell modules become unavailable?

When I create a process with `CreateProcess()` and the command line

`powershell -Command "Get-Module -ListAvailable"`

I don't get all the modules I get when executing the same statement from a command prompt.

Are there any fields I have to set inside the STARTUPINFO or PROCESS_INFORMATION structs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some modules are not available in the 32 bit version of PowerShell. On Windows Server 2008 R2 with PowerShell v1.0 these are:

- ADRMS
- AppLocker
- BestPractices
- ServerManager

Answer (score 2):

The set of modules available is controlled by the `PSModulePath` environment variable.  It's possible that the two processes in question here have 2 different values for `PSModulePath` and hence you see 2 different sets of modules.

Can you check the value in both cases and see if it's different?

Comment: No, it had the same path in both cases. But thanks for your answer. It made me realize that I was executing on different architectures (32 bits vs. 64 bits).